# MySQL timestamp column sometimes receives value which is well after the INSERT completes

Tags: mysql, performance, insert, timestamp

**NOTE** The problem was solved: it seems this was caused by a later REPLACE on the same record.

I have a table with a timestamp column marking when a record was inserted:

```
insert_timestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The table has grown quite big over time - currently ~5.7M records.

To help you understand why I'm asking this, I need to explain that I have an application that tries to make use of the inserted data as soon as it's inserted, in an asynchronous manner from the code that inserts the record into the DB.
In many cases it works nicely, and I see that the process is nearly instantaneous. However, I also see some cases where the insert_timestamp value is much larger than the time the record was inserted. The MySQL documentation for the TIMESTAMP data type does not have any explanation why this might happen.

My suspicion is that this might be due to index rebuilding issues, although I don't understand why the timestamp cannot be set to the moment of the insertion.

Do you have idea why this happens ? any insight or thoughts will also be appreciated.

Thanks,
Yaron

Note: although the insert_timestamp column is defined with ON UPDATE, records in this table are never really updated.

Below is the full structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `checkins` (
`type` enum('Change','Add','Remove') DEFAULT NULL,
`ci_when` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`whoid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`repositoryid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`dirid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fileid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`revision` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`prevrevision` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`stickytag` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`branchid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`addedlines` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`removedlines` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`descid` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`reviewid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`insert_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE KEY `repositoryid` (`repositoryid`,`dirid`,`fileid`,`revision`),
KEY `ci_when` (`ci_when`),
KEY `whoid` (`whoid`,`ci_when`),
KEY `dirid` (`dirid`),
KEY `fileid` (`fileid`),
KEY `branchid` (`branchid`),
KEY `reviewid` (`reviewid`),
KEY `file_insert` (`dirid`,`fileid`,`insert_timestamp`),
KEY `insert_ts` (`insert_timestamp`),
KEY `its2` (`insert_timestamp`,`branchid`,`dirid`,`fileid`,`repositoryid`),
KEY `branch_its` (`branchid`,`insert_timestamp`,`dirid`,`fileid`,`repositoryid`),
KEY `review_and_branch` (`reviewid`,`branchid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Some more info:

- insertion rate is usually rather slow. Last 24 hours it was 361 records. Sometimes it can be much more (even over 100K in a day), but not often. The latency issue that I'm researching happens regardless of insertion rate.
- The server has 8 CPUs, 12GB RAM
- OS: Linux/Debian 2.6.32-5-amd64
- Disks: system: 130GB, data: 60 GB, 58% used, raid 1, 82% idle
- MySQL 5.1.6.3
- Server variables:

  - innodb_adaptive_hash_index         ON
  - innodb_additional_mem_pool_size    1048576
  - innodb_autoextend_increment        8
  - innodb_autoinc_lock_mode           1
  - innodb_buffer_pool_size            8589934592
  - innodb_checksums                   ON
  - innodb_commit_concurrency          0
  - innodb_concurrency_tickets         500
  - innodb_data_file_path              ibdata1:10M:autoextend
  - innodb_data_home_dir
  - innodb_doublewrite                 ON
  - innodb_fast_shutdown               1
  - innodb_file_io_threads             4
  - innodb_file_per_table              ON
  - innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit     1
  - innodb_flush_method
  - innodb_force_recovery              0
  - innodb_lock_wait_timeout           50
  - innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog     OFF
  - innodb_log_buffer_size             1048576
  - innodb_log_file_size               5242880
  - innodb_log_files_in_group          2
  - innodb_log_group_home_dir          ./
  - innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct         90
  - innodb_max_purge_lag               0
  - innodb_mirrored_log_groups         1
  - innodb_open_files                  300
  - innodb_rollback_on_timeout         OFF
  - innodb_stats_method                nulls_equal
  - innodb_stats_on_metadata           ON
  - innodb_support_xa                  ON
  - innodb_sync_spin_loops             20
  - innodb_table_locks                 ON
  - innodb_thread_concurrency          8
  - innodb_thread_sleep_delay          10000
  - innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm  ON

Comment: Are  you sure there are no updates? Have you tested if same thing happens after removing the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: Hi @ypercube,

No, I haven't checked what happens if I remove the ON UPDATE.
The code that does the insertion is actually using REPLACE INTO, but OTOH it also checks to add only what's new.

Comment: `REPLACE` does an insert, unless it finds a duplicate primary key (or unique in your case) where it does a delete and an insert. Better re-examine that code (that you say it checks to add only new). Or include it in the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Probably should just replace the REPLACE (forgive my pun...) with INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: I updated the code to use INSERT IGNORE instead of REPLACE, and saw no further cases of the said 'delay'. Why it was inserted twice remains to be investigated, but it's not really that important so I'll probably just leave it at that.